# Mosaic generator with variable size tiles

Tags: images, image-processing, photography

I am looking for a [mosaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_mosaic) generator that allow you to use variable size tiles. Most generators allow you to only use fixed-size, square tiles. [Some of the more advanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AndreaMosaic) allow you to non-square tiles:

[image: Mosaic generator that allows non-rectangular tiles]

However, none that I have found so far allows variable-size tiles. That is, let's say that one tile is 2:2, another is 3:5, another is 2:10, etc.

Is there a mosaic software that allows variable-size-tiles?

The software should accept a directory of images to be used as the tiles in the mosaic and an input image and act on these inputs.

This would ideally be free-of-charge and run on Mac, but I am open to answers for any OS and proprietary software.

Comment: Welcome aboard. Please read [ask]. For instance, which operating system should the software run on? If you have a budget in mind, please state it; if the application should cost nothing, please us the [tag:gratis] tag. The more details that you can give us, the better that we can help you. Do you want to specify the sizes yourself, or should the application choose them, based on t he image? I hope that you get a answer, as I would like this too :-)

Comment: Are you looking for a static mosaic (such as one that will be printed as a poster), or a dynamic mosaic with zooming (such as you might display on a web page)?

Comment: @browly Static.